# Get 1 record against combination of columns with matching condition sql

Tags: sql

```
----------tbldata---------------------------
ispickable  returnId    inventoryId locationId      
1           3030567     234649       29647
NULL        3030567     234649       29648


1           3030568     234650       29649
1           3030569     234651       29650


NULL        3030571     234653       29647
```

Resultant Data should be like:

```
ispickable  returnId    inventoryId locationId      
1           3030567     234649       29647
1           3030568     234650       29649
1           3030569     234651       29650
NULL        3030571     234653       29647
```

We have  to get 1 record against combination of returnId and inventoryId.

Conditions :
We will get 1 record against combination of returnId and inventoryId, against which ispickable=1.
If we have no record against combination of returnId and inventoryId with ispickable=1, then we will get record with ispickable=null.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`.  This is a type of prioritization query:

```
select ispickable, returnId, inventoryId, locationId
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by returnId, inventoryId
                                order by ispickable desc  -- nulls go last
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tbldata t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tbldata
  where returnid = t.returnid and inventoryid = t.inventoryid
  and ispickable > coalesce(t.ispickable, 0)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7d3e266d3d74febc01cac6db45c8dc8c).
Results:

```
> ispickable | returnId | inventoryId | locationId
> :--------- | -------: | ----------: | ---------:
> 1          |  3030567 |      234649 |      29647
> 1          |  3030568 |      234650 |      29649
> 1          |  3030569 |      234651 |      29650
> null       |  3030571 |      234653 |      29647
```